# Is Nix Php-ready?

Tags: nix

I'm new to Nix and quite excited about it (I've been using it so far for Haskell).
I'm planning to use it to deploy Php applications. However, how Nix deals with
Php packages (installed normally or with pear).

Comment: You should track the issue here: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/24432

Comment: The main issue is the difference between PHP extensions and PHP packages. For packages you can just use composer inside a nix-shell, for extensions, there's some work on making it similar to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a week trying to configure a LAMP platform and giving up (mainly because I couldn't make PHP send emails), I concluded that Nix is not ready for developping easily PHP application in production.

Comment: This might not be the best place to ask Nix questions. Have you tried the IRC channel or mailing list? (I use NixOS on a server with PHP-FPM without problems.)

Answer (score 5):

Working with PHP webapps generally requires several *running services* (`php-fpm`, `httpd`, `mysqld`, `redis`, etc). The answer depends on how you manage the services -- which, in turn, depends on whether you use:

- (a) **The full *NixOS***: NixOS provides a service-management layer - you edit a config file, twiddle some flags, and turn on the services. I haven't done this myself, and I think it needs a more pointed tutorial for folks coming from a PHP webdev background, but the system does exist.
- (b) **The crossplatform `nix`/`nixpkgs`**: There does not appear to be a canonical service-management option here. `nix` basically just gives some binaries (`php-fpm`, `mysqld`, etc) which you can launch yourself. It's somewhat daunting for typical PHP developer.

*Full disclosure*: To try to improve the situation for crossplatform `nix`+PHP, I've written an example project `locolamp`. It won't help much with learning NixOS, but it may help get your toes wet with `nix`+`php` in cross-platform usage. See:

https://github.com/totten/locolamp